# setInterval() not firing

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run some code endlessly. I want to use the setInterval() method for that. The problem I am having with my program is that it is not getting executed at all. I tried to find the error using the browser's console but it does not say any error. I checked all the methods that are called before setInterval() are exectued properly. Here is the basic code :-

```
"use strict";
var Main = {
    //properties

    initialize: 
        setInterval(this.gameLoop, 15);
    },

    gameLoop: function(){

    }

    //other methods
}

window.addEventListener("load", Main.initialize, false);
```

Comment: Are you getting call of this.gameLoop function at all?

Comment: @c-smile nope not at all.  this.gameLoop is not executed even once.

Comment: And what is that this.gameLoop ? Is it a function?

Comment: @c-smile Yes. I edited the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `this` is referencing the `window` object instead of the main object. See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5noa7m4L/2/)

**Solution 1**

Change the `setInterval` to:

```
setInterval(Main.gameLoop, 15);
```

**Solution 2**

Change the `load` event to:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() { Main.initialise.call(Main); }, false);
```

**Object Way**

```
function Main() {
    // The constructor
}

Main.prototype.initialise = function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        this.gameLoop();
    }, 15);
}

Main.prototype.gameLoop = function() {
    // Do gameloop stuff
}

var main = new Main();
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    main.initialise();
}, false);
```

Please note, I'm using initiali**s**e instead of initiali**z**e because its how I spell it (Just in case you direct copy paste and wonder why its not working for some bits)

Comment: why is the 'this' keyword referring to 'window' object instead of the 'Main' object? Shouldn't it refer to the owner of the method I am executing?

Comment: `this` refers to whatever calls the function. By default when you invoke a method on a non instance it will pass through the current context (IE: `window` because that was the last context)

Comment: Your variable `Main` is really just an associative array with a function as one of the values. I'll edit my answer to show how one would typically do it using an "object" way.

Comment: i read some articles about this and did some research but all of them says that this refers to the current object, but i don't understand why in my case it is referring to the window object.

Comment: That is correct, and the current object is window, since Main isn't an "object" in a callable sense. Main is more of a dictionary containing a function. So the current object remains the window

Comment: Well, calling `.call(something)` will make `this` inside the function equal to that variable

Comment: Main is not an object? but the tutorials clearly says that you create objects in java script using var ObjectName = { properties and methods} ?  I am doing the same thing, so how is Main not an object ?

Comment: Main is an object, but not in a callable sense. Js only has associative arrays. All you are doing is defining an associative array with key initialise and a function stored as that keys value. You need to instantiate an instance to be able to call the functions (see my object way)

Comment: You could possibly try modifying your existing code with a `var main = new Main()`, as that might work. You will still need to wrap the call to initialise in the `function(){}`